# Twisted and Tornado difference when deploying?

Tags: twisted, tornado

I only have a small knowledge about Tornado, and when it comes to deployement, it is better to use Nginx as a load balancer with the number of Tornado process.

How about Twisted? is that the same way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm tracking your question right, you seem to be asking:  "Should Tornado be front-ended with Nginx, how about Twisted?"

If thats really where the question is going, then its got a "it depends" answer but perhaps in a way that you might not expect.  **In a runtime sense, twisted, tornado and Nginx are** in more ways than not **the same thing**.

All three of these systems use the same programming pattern in their core.  Something the OO people call a Reactor pattern, which is often also known as asynchronous I/O event programming, and something that old-school unix people would call a `select` style event loop. (done via `select` / `epoll` / `kqueue` / `WaitForMultipleObjects` / etc)

### To build up to the answer, some background:

- **Twisted** is a Reactor based framework that **was created to for** writing python based **asynchronous I/O** projects in their most generic form.  So while its extremely good for web applications (via the [Twisted Web](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb) sub-module), its equally good for dealing with Serial data (via the [SerialPort](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.serialport.html) sub-module) or implementing a totally different networking protocol like [ssh](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.conch.ssh.html).

Twisted excels in flexibility. If you need to glue many IO types together, and particularly if you want to connect IOs to the web it is fantastic. As noted in remudada answer, it also has application tool built in ([`twistd`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html)).

As an async I/O framework, Twisted has very few weaknesses.  As a *web framework* though (while it is actively continuing to evolve) it feel decidedly behind the curve particularly as compared to plugin rich frameworks like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), and Tornado definitely has many web conveniences over Twisted Web.

- **Torando** is a Reactor based framework in python, that **was created to for** serving **webpages/webapps** extremely fast (basically as fast as python can be made to serve up webpages).  The folks who wrote it were aiming to write a system so fast that the production code itself could be python.

The Tornado core is nearly a logically match to the core of Twisted. The core of these projects are so similar that on modern releases you can run [Twisted inside of Tornado](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twisted.html) or run a [Tornado port inside of Twisted](http://cyclone.io).

Tornado is single-mindedly focused on serving webpages/webapps fast.  In most applications it will be 20%ish faster then Twisted Web, but nowhere near as flexible as supporting other async I/O uses.  It (like twisted) is still python based, so if a given webapp does too much CPU based work its performance will fall quickly.

- **Nginx** is a Reactor based *application* that **was created to for** serving **webpages and connection redirection** written **in C**. While Twisted and Tornado use the Reactor pattern to make python go fast, Nginx takes things to next step and uses that logic in C.

When people compare Python and C they often talk about Python being 1.2 to 100 times slower.  However, in the Reactor pattern (which when done right spends most of it's time in operating system) language inefficiency is minimized - as long as not too much logic happens outside of the reactor.

I don't have hard data to back this up but my expectation is that you would find the simplest "Hello world" (I.E. serving static test) running no more then 50% slower on Tornado then on Nginx (with Twisted Web being 20% slower then Tornado on average).

### Differences speed of the same thing, where does that leave us?

You asked "it is better to use Nginx as a load balancer with the number of Tornado process", so to answer that I need to ask you question back.

> **Are you deploying in a way where its critical that you take advanced of multiple cores?**

In exchange for blazing async IO speed, the Reactor pattern has a weakness:

- Each Reactor can only take advantage of one process core.

As you might guess, the flip side of that weakness is that the Reactor pattern uses that core extremely efficiently and if you have the load, should be able to take that core near 100% use.

This leads back to the type of design your asking about, but the reason for all the background in this answer is because the layering of these services (Nginx in front of Tornado or Twisted) should only be done **to take advantage of multi-core machines**.

If your running on a single core system (lowest class cloud server or an embedded platform like a Raspberry Pi) you SHOULD NOT front-end a reactor.  Doing so will simple slow the whole system down.

If you run more (heavily loaded) reactor services then CPU cores, your also going to be working against yourself.

So:

- if you're deploying on single core system:

  - Run one instance of either a Tornado or Twisted (or Nginx alone if its static pages)
- if your trying to fully exploit multiple cores

  - Run Nginx (or twisted) on the application port, run one instance of Tornado or Twisted for each remaining processor core.

Comment: This is tangential to the original question, but just to set the record straight, the Tornado developers were aware of Twisted and deliberately set out to build a different set of abstractions for async development (e.g. IOStream vs Transport/Protocol).  The core event loop ended up getting duplicated, but this is small in comparison to all the supporting infrastructure that surrounds it.

Comment: i never used Twisted, since i am happy with Tornado, it was a friend who worked on an application with Twisted, and debated with him about using a load balancer due to Python nature, so i guess it will be the same logic between Twisted and Tornado?

Comment: Both Twisted and Tornado should look the same vis-à-vis balancers (as I suspect you would find for any other Reactor based system, I.E. thing like node.js).  Holy wars can be started when talking about Tornado vs Twisted but as they have the same core, their use-case tends to be the same -- excluding devop customizations, which could aid or hinder either framework.

Comment: even Tornado is trying to get rid from Nginx, so the answer is Twisted and Tornado have the same deployment behind Nginx when the latter is used as load balancer?

Comment: Yes.  There would only be cosmetic differences (like tools that automatically fork the service into the background) between Twisted and Tornado.  The way you would run serivces on multiple different ports, and configure those ports into Nginx would be precisely the same (... again, barring some 3rd party tools you added on that made things work differently).

Answer (score 1):

Twisted is a good enough application server on it's own and I would rather use it as it is (unlike Tornado)

If you look at the offical guide http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/core/howto/application.html

you can see how it is set up. Ofcourse you can use uwsgi / nginx / emperor with twsited since it can be run as a standard application, but I would suggest that you do this when you really need the scaling and load balancing.

Comment: both have the same concept (callbacks) so i said that it is the same way they behave with sockets, so it will be the same when deplyong?

Comment: Unless you are using the latest version of uwsgi 2.0 (with async socket support) there should be no difference. I have had little luck with 2.0. But as always, try the setup and you would know :-)